# Creating weighted list using Select tool in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, sql

I've done a raster to point conversion and have a column of the grid codes.

Let's say it is composed of 10 numbers [9,5,7,1,7,3,7,2,8,1].

Right now I am doing a selection on those numbers based on the top 50% of the Max value(Select values greater than 4.5, which gives {9,8,7,7,7,5})

What I would like to do is take the original array and select all of the values that make up greater than 50% of the total(Total is 68/2 = 34, so SUM(9,8,7,7,7) > 34) and have those as my selection points.

I think I can sort the data and use another 1 or 2 calculate fields to get the sum of the column and the 50% value, but how would I go about adding the values to get above 50% and save them as the selection?